# How to set the width of a column of a dynamic HTML table

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table, width

I have code as below

```
 <table >
    <thead >
        <th *ngFor="let col of workData.columns;trackBy: trackByColumn;
            let hindex=index;" [ngClass]="setWidth(col)" [index]="hindex">
        </th>
    </thead>
</table>


 //TS File

  setWidth(col){
   if(col.field === 'First Name') {
   col.width = '100px';
 }
}
```

In the above table, I get both column names List and column Data from the Http call and render the table based on it. 
How do I dynamically set width for each column based on its name.

for ex:

`Column: First Name    Width:100px
 Column: Last Name     Width:90px
 Column:  Address      Width: 150px`

I am using `Angular 6`. I tried javascript solutions and also with `ngClass` and `ngStyle` in angular. But I am not able to get a handle on how to set width to each of the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ngClass]` expects an object. You are calling a method that returns nothing

One possible way is to bind the `style` property.

**component.ts**

```
  public styles=
  {
    'First Name' : '100px',
    'Last Name' : '90px',
    'Address' : '150px'
  };
```

**component.html**

```
 <table >
    <thead >
        <th [style.width]="styles[col.field]" 
            *ngFor="let col of workData.columns; let hindex=index;" >
          {{col.field}}
        </th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-i9ogvu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You could do the same with classes (e.g. `class=classes[col.field]`)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a JSON object widht a 'style' attribute like this:

`workData = {
       columns: [
       {
        field: "First Name",
        style: {
          width: "100px",
          "background-color": "red",
          color: "white"
        }
      },
      {
        field: "Last Name",
        style: {
          width: "200px",
          "background-color": "blue",
          color: "white"
        }
      },
      {
        field: "Address",
        style: {
          width: "300px",
          "background-color": "yellow",
          color: "black"
        }
      }
    ]};`

then in your file.html

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <th [ngStyle]="col.style" *ngFor="let col of workData.columns;">{{col.field}}</th>
 </thead>
</table>
```

now you can add more than one style on your table

[click here to see it running](https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-in-table-headings)